# Are all 2D tensors in a specified flat metric equal to that same metric conformally scaled?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

I have a tensor $T_{mn}$ where its indices coorespond to a flat metric $g_{mn}$. I want $T_{mn}$ to be a new metric $\tilde{g}_{mn}$, such that $T_{mn}(g_{rs}) = \tilde{g}_{mn}$.

A theorem says that all 2D metrics are conformally flat. So does their exists a conformal factor $\phi$, such that 
\begin{align}
T_{mn}(g_{rs}) = \phi g_{mn}
&&
(1)
\end{align}
is possible? If so, does this imply that $T_{n}{}^{n}{}=\phi$?

The confusing element in this problem is $T_{mn}$'s indices correspond to the indices of the flat metric $g_{mn}$ from which it was created. The above may be incorrect, and a new metric flat metric $h_{mn}$ must be created to allow
\begin{align}
T_{mn}(g_{rs}) = \phi h_{mn}
&&
(2)
\end{align}
where $h_{mn}\neq g_{mn}$.

Are all 2D tensors in a specified flat metric equal to that same metric conformally scaled?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How is $T_{mn}$ related to $g_{rs}$? What does it mean for the index to "correspond"? // Aside: it is certainly not true that any two symmetric bilinear form are proportional. You can check this even on the level o matrices.

Comment: @WillieWong My math language is still developing. I meant 'index to correspond' to mean the same coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand enough of your question to give an answer.

> **No**

And that is because two flat metrics on the same 2D manifold do not have to be conformal. To wit, let $\mathbb{T}^2$ denote the torus. The metrics with line elements

$$ \mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}x^2  + \mathrm{d}y^2 $$

and

$$ \mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}x^2 + 2 \mathrm{d} y^2 $$

are both flat, but are not conformal to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this imply that equation 1 is incorrect, and equation 2 is correct?

Comment: neither are correct, given what you have written. Since it is in fact possible that, by some cosmic coincidence, that $h_{mn} = g_{mn}$.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I misunderstood what the conformal metric theorem meant for 2D metrics. How am I misusing the theorem?

Comment: My previous comment only was meant to address what you wrote immediately following equation (2), which I regard as part of the same sentence, which asserts $h \neq g$. // You are not misusing the theorem. It is the deduction after applying that theorem that has problems.  Just that on (1) two flat metrics on the same manifold need not be isometric (2) furthermore, two flat metrics on the same manifold need not be isometric _under the identity map_.

Comment: I am struggling with understanding my flawed deduction. To be more specific, I have the following equation $T^{mn}\nabla_{m}\nabla_{n}=\phi g^{mn}\nabla_{m}\nabla_{n}$ which I stated was true, where $\phi = T^{n}{}_{n}{}$. Does this equation use the same flawed deduction?

Comment: In your comment above, is $g$ a given fixed background metric, or is $g$ the metric generated from the theorem about conformal metrics? In the former, your deduction is invalid. In the latter, your deduction is okay. In other words, you know that $T$ is proportional to some flat metric, except you don't know which one.

Comment: Or is it that I do not know what the conformal factor is? I was trying to prove that the weighted rank 2 tensor sum of covariant derivatives always equals a Laplace operator times a conformal factor in 2D, but now I am unsure if that is correct.

Comment: What you want to prove is false in general; because in the expression $T^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu$ the covariant derivatives $\nabla$ are defined relative to _something_, and that something doesn't have to be the metric that $T$ is conformal to. On the other hand, what is true is that in 2D any Laplacian is equal to a conformal factor times a flat Laplacian. (And with this I am going to bed. )

Comment: What confuses me is more is the fact that all flat metrics are equivalent under a coordinate transformation. Doesn't $\nabla_m$ imply any choice of metric?

Comment: @linuxfreebird: no. Three problems. (a) Think about the formula of Laplacian in spherical coordinates; it contains a first-order derivative term! (b) flat metrics are **locally** isometric. There is not guarantee the local coordinate transformation can be extended globally. (c) You already gave up your "coordinate change" degree of freedom when you said "index to correspond" which you took to mean "within the same coordinate system". Once you fixed something, you cannot transform it!